# Typing record of functions from a function signature in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to type memoized selectors in a record in Typescript.

I defined :

```js
type StateFunction<State> = (state: State) => any;
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

type ExtractReturnType<T extends AnyFunction[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[I]>;
};

type MemoizeTuple<T extends AnyFunction[]> = [
  T,
  (...args: ExtractReturnType<T>) => any
];
```

SIMPLE CASE

If I want to type a function that takes as a parameter a memoized tuple and returns the resulting selector, I have :

```js
type MkSelector<State> = <T extends StateFunction<State>[], F>(
  memoizeTyple: MemoizeTuple<[...T]> & F
) => F extends [infer _, infer B]
  ? (state: State) => B extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never
  : never;
```

Let say that I have a state defined as follow:

```js
type State = {
foo: number;
bar: string;
};
```

And the selectors for foo and bar :

```js
const selectFoo = (state: State) => state.foo;

const selectBar = (state: State) => state.bar;
```

Then if I declare my function, according to type MkSelector
(I don't care about the implementation, this is not the difficult part),
then I have :

```js
declare const mkSelector: MkSelector<State>;

const selector = mkSelector([[selectFoo, selectBar], (foo, bar) => null]);
```

And Typescript, infers selector as :

```js
const selector: (state: State) => null
```

And the inner function as :  `(foo: number, bar: string) => null`

Which is the expected result.

My final goal to get the desired result for a record of tuples. Getting help from the re-select implementation, I came up with :

```js
type BuildMkSelectors<State> = <
  T extends { [K in keyof T]: StateFunction<State>[] },
  F
>(
  t: {
    [K in keyof T]: MemoizeTuple<[...T[K]]>;
  } & F
) => {
  [K in keyof F]: F[K] extends [any, infer B]
    ? (state: State) => B extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never
    : never;
};
```

When applying this :

```js
declare const buildMkSelectors: BuildMkSelectors<State>;

const selectors = buildMkSelectors({
  sel1: [[selectFoo], (foo) => 42],
  sel2: [[selectBar], (bar) => true],
  sel3: [[selectFoo, selectBar], (foo, bar) => null],
});
```

Typescript infers selectors as :

```js
 const selectors: {
    sel1: (state: State) => number;
    sel2: (state: State) => boolean;
    sel3: (state: State) => null;
}
```

And the inner tuples as :

```js
{
    sel1: (foo: number) => number;
    sel2: (bar: string) => boolean;
    sel3: (foo: number, bar: string) => null;

}
```

Which is exactly what I was looking for.

FINAL GOAL

I want to create a generic type to rewrite BuildMkSelectors in a cleaner way,
just using BuildMkSelector.

Something like:

```js
type FOverRecord<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
  // iterate over F
};
```

So that :

```js
type BuildMkSelectors2<State> = FOverRecord<MkSelector<State>>;
```

Would be strictly equivalent to BuildMkSelectors.

I am stuck there, is that possible to achieve this?

Comment: Nice work so far! A question, do you need selectors to be so generic? If you can tighten scope of the selectors, it would require less typescript magic.

Comment: Thank you Lex! Yes kind of, at least I would like it to work with the example I provided. I picked up this particular example, which is on purpose not trivial, because, there is a good chance that if it works with it it will work with many of my use cases. But the real goal is to get the FOverRecord (or call it as you want) type. There are many places in my project where it could help save quite a lot of code.

Comment: I'm... trying to walk through this and understand what you're doing in order to understand the question, and... I'm getting distracted by things.  Why do `ExtractReturnType` and `MemoizeTuple` take two type arguments if they don't do anything with the first one?  Your use of `index` as a type parameter is unconventional; maybe `I`?  Your use of `State` as both a specific type and a type parameter is confusing.  I'm not saying any of these things are important, just that it would be nice to not have to deal with them. Could you [edit] to address these?

Comment: (see prev comment) Just on first glance I wouldn't think this is possible. TS doesn't have a way to instantiate type arguments in generic functions at the type level (see [ms/TS#50481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50481) for the feature request) and because `MkSelector<State>` has all the information you care about bound up inside a generic function, it's therefore impossible to extract. Looking at this you'd probably also need higher kinded types as per [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) and possibly other stuff. I'd say: this is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback jcalz, I applied both of your edit requests. I suspected this might be difficult without HKT. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: So, assuming it's not possible, would you be interested in an answer post that says this is impossible and why? I'm not sure I'm prepared to *write* such an answer right now (it's kind of depressing to write about all kinds of missing features) but I'm wondering if such a thing would be helpful to future readers or not.

Comment: Most times I struggle with Typescript, I end up here or on github, and it's generally related to missing higher kinded types. Can be quite confusing, so if you are up to write a detailed "once for all, this is not possible" and here's why, it's likely I would not be the only one interested!